# How to check for array containing only an empty object [{}]

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which is as follows.

```
let response = [
 {}
];
```

Which is an array with an empty object. What kind of check should I put in place to determine if this response is exactly equal to this. i.e,

```
[{}] === response; // returns false
```

I want to have a check that returns false if the response is `[{}]` how do i do that.

There are already questions on stack-overflow which asks on how to check for an empty object. My Question is that how do I check for an array with an empty object. So completely different. This is no duplicate of any question.

Comment: FWIW, if an array contains an object then it is not empty.

Comment: one way `JSON.stringify(response) === '[{}]'`

Comment: I would try something like that: `Array.isArray(response) && response.length === 1 && typeof response[1] === 'object' && Object.keys(response[1]).length === 0`

Comment: See https://coderwall.com/p/_g3x9q/how-to-check-if-javascript-object-is-empty

Comment: @FelixKling this is not a duplicate of that question. As this question ask an empty object inside an array. That question asks only for an empty object. :)

Comment: Setting this kind of single element array with an empty object is something I’ve never done, it feels like bad practice for some reason.  You will be forever referring to response[0] in your code.  imo response should either be an empty array or empty object which is later wrapped in an array.

Comment: @AdeelImran: I would expect that you know how to check the length of the array and how to access the first element :) *"So completely different."* Not quite. Checking the emptiness of an object is a part of your problem.

Comment: Yes sir I do know on how to do that @FelixKling I just wanted to see what was the best way on how to do that.

Comment: `arr.length === 1 && isEmptyObject(arr[0])` where `isEmptyObject` is an implementation suggested in the other question.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have checked. I think that does help me.

Comment: I always try to split a problem into sub-problems and search for solutions for those first (such as how to test whether an object is empty in this case). Sure, there might be "better" solutions for the complete problem, but I might get to a solution faster by solving the sub-problems first.

Comment: Sir I am new to the industry, a recent graduate. Just still learning on how to be a great problem solver. I do know I have a very long way to go. I strongly believe you can achieve greatness if you have a mentor. I am a self taught dev. So just trying to learn on my own as much as I can. @FelixKling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if it is an array, with `Array.isArray`, then check the `.length` to see if it's one, then check if the first element is an empty object (`typeof` and `Object.keys().length === 0`). That way you'll be pretty sure it's what you wanted.

Another option is to use json: `JSON.stringify(response) ==== '[{}]'`. Just beware of cyclic dependencies in response.

Comment: Thank you sir. This helped.

Comment: just an FYI, `typeof []` is `object`, and `Object.keys([]).length` is 0, so you might want to do  a different check for object

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
let response = [{}];

console.log(JSON.stringify([{}]) === JSON.stringify([{}])); // true,
```

But if your response is cyclic, this will fail.

Another way you can do is:

```
let response = [{}];


console.log(
  Array.isArray(response) &&
    response.length === 1 &&
    Object.prototype.toString.call(response[0]) === '[object Object]' &&
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(response[0]).length === 0
); // true
```

Comment: For the cyclic problem, I believe there is an option for stringify that will go just n-levels deep, fixing the problem (if the structure is cyclic, it certainly going to be different 2-level deep anyway). I'd need to look it up, though

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Object.keys(response[0] || {}).length === 0
```

Comment: It could be an array with more than one element, but might work for most use-cases ;)

Comment: Wont work in case of `[[]]` as `Object.keys([]).length` is 0

Comment: @AyushGupta But that's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Perhaps, but if the OP needs to check for that response exactly, and `[[]]` is a valid response , yours wont be 100% reliable