# How to check for an object of empty arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to check if an object has only empty arrays left. Here is an example of the object:

```
var obj = {
   arr1: [0, 1, 2],
   arr2: [1, 2, 3],
   arr3: [2, 3, 4]
};
```

I have been `pop()`ing off values from the arrays inside the object and then I need to check if all of the arrays are empty.

One method I have thought of is like so:

```
var isEmpty = true;
for (var item in obj) {
   if (obj[item] !== 0) {
      isEmpty = false;
   }
}
// now isEmpty reflects the state of all the object's arrays being empty
```

However, I am wondering if there is a more simple and straightforward solution.
I've looked around and [answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32108184/8804293) don't work because the *object* isn't empty, the arrays *inside of* the object are. My question is kind of the inverse of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47908779/8804293).

Comment: Interesting question.  Here's a very non-simple and very non-straightforward solution, that actually works: `var totalLength=0;
for(item of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).split("{").join("[").split("}").join("]").split(":").join(","))) if(item.length==0) totalLength+=item.length;
console.log("obj's arrays are "+(totalLength?"Not":"")+"empty");`

Answer (score 2):

You could get the values and check each array with their length.

```js
const areAllEmpty = object => !Object.values(object).some(({ length }) => length);

console.log(areAllEmpty({ a: [], b: [], c: [] }));   //  true
console.log(areAllEmpty({ a: [1], b: [], c: [] }));  // false
console.log(areAllEmpty({ a: [], b: [1], c: [] }));  // false
console.log(areAllEmpty({ a: [1], b: [2], c: [] })); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `every` method on the object values:

```js
var obj = {
   arr1: [0, 1, 2],
   arr2: [1, 2, 3],
   arr3: [2, 3, 4]
};

const hasEmptyArrays = obj => 
  Object.values(obj).every(arr => arr.length === 0)

console.log(hasEmptyArrays(obj))
```